# 95|Session|Inactive conversation and header invalid for Amadeus API

Tags: php, amadeus

I keep on getting error with

> 95|session|inactive conversation

I already refresh the request before to get a new session id and security token, but it still getting the error. The API I'm using is for hotel. There's 7 step, I get the error for step 4 `get_enhanced_price`, 5 `pnr_request` and 7 `pnr_request`.

Second error is for step 6 `sell_request`. It shows:

> A header representing a Message Addressing Property is not valid and
> the message cannot be processed

Anyone can help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this issue today and we have been advised to change the 'action' and the 'SOAPAction' elements.
For example if the SOAPHeader the 'Action' is #http://webservices.amadeus.com/FMPTBQ_14_3_1A

While in the HTTP Header the 'action' and the 'SOAPAction' are
!http://webservices.amadeus.com/FMPTBQ_
http://webservices.amadeus.com/FMPTBQ_14_3_1A (this one has the version id)

So, I suggest you to change the 'action' and the 'SOAPAction' elements
to
http://webservices.amadeus.com/FMPTBQ_14_3_1A

Check your request to see what you are sending in the request for the action and SOAP action as one of them may have the version ID and the other may not.

I think this is the reason for the error.

Comment: Link-only answers are generally [frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/204922) on Stack Overflow. In time it is possible for links to atrophy and become unavailable, meaning that your answer is useless to users in the future. It would be best if you could provide the general details of your answer in your actual post, citing your link as a reference.

Comment: I can't reach any of your links.

Comment: @Blaztix - This isn't a Link-Only answer.

The "links" that were provided are URLs in the SOAP XML. These are valid endpoints that are called when using the provided SOAP api and not to be used in any other way. No you can't see anything when you click it and not you won't see anything when you send an XMLHTTPRequest because it's not supposed to be used like that.

Kmilia - I would suggest reading up on how SOAP works and/or contact your Amadeus agent to help you with your issue.